# Ruby with Tk in Gentoo

Tags: gentoo, ruby, tcl

How to emerge Ruby with tk/tcl support in Gentoo Linux. I've tried `USE="tk" emerge ruby`, but it didn't work. Furthermore there is no tk use flag according "https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/dev-lang/ruby"

Comment: Have you installed `dev-lang/tk`?

Comment: Yes I have. I've installed tk and tcl and it didn't help.

Comment: See my answer below.  What is the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's test your Ruby installations.  In each version of Ruby you have installed, run this little snippet:

```
require 'tk'

root = TkRoot.new { title "Hello, World!" }
TkLabel.new(root) do
   text 'Hello, World!'
   pack { padx 15 ; pady 15; side 'left' }
end
Tk.mainloop
```

What happens when you run this?

---

### Solution

Having tested your installation, I went hunting, and found this little snippet of code in all ebuilds folder in `/usr/portage/dev-lang/ruby`:

```
# The Tk module can no longer be built because the module code is no
# longer compatible with newer stable versions.
# https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=500894
```

I present [Bug 500894 - dev-lang/tcl 8.5.15 and 8.6.1-r1 both needed on ~ but only 8.5.15 can be installed](https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=500894) for your reading pleasure. Consider using another GUI toolkit.  Some choices available in the tree are:

- `kde-base/qtruby`
- `dev-ruby/fxruby`

Comment: `/usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- tk (LoadError)
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 from test.rb:1:in `<main>'`